# React state not updating with socket

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

This is my simple react component:
`const PlayersOnline = () => {
const socket = useSocket();

```
const [onlinePlayers, setOnlinePlayers] = useState(1);

socket.on("online_players", (data) => {
    console.log("data coming ----", data);
    setOnlinePlayers(() => {
        console.log("state----", data);

        return data;
    });
});

return (
    <div className="playersOnline">
        <p>Online: {onlinePlayers}</p>
    </div>
);
```

};`

The socket instant is being created and utilised using context throughout the components. I have put down two consoles also, one in "online_players" callback and another just before returning data.
There is no issue in socket connection, It updates state without any issue on the first render, but when I go to another page where this component is not used, and come back to this, the socket event triggers, I can see the log "data coming --- " with value, but after that the setState code doesnt execute. Can some one point out the fix for this issue why is it not able to execute the whole code, it dont event give any error.

I have also used the useEffect approach but that make things worse as it doesnt even let the socket event trigger.

Comment: Are you adding a new event listener to the socket on every render? It's hard to tell without a slightly more complete code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I have sent two events in wrong order from my server, tweaking that order fixed it.

Its resolved now.

But I am still wondering why the code is reaching till the first console.log line and not executing the very next without any break or any error.